# Doctrine DQL how to write SELECT EXISTS

Tags: doctrine, dql

This is based on valid SQL but I cannot get it to work in DQL

```
SELECT 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT activity FROM Entity\Activity activity
        WHERE activity MEMBER OF person.activities
        AND activity.name = 'sports'
   ) AS doesSports,
   person.id 
FROM Entity\Person person
```

This gives the error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'EXISTS'
```

EXISTS seems to work like this after WHERE but not in select

Answer (score 0):

The grammer does not permit so-called "Other Expressions" in the SELECT clause, only functions are allowed.